# Verifying value before parsing

Tags: java, error-handling, null

I am writing some Java code and am coming across a try/catch block in which I decided to verify the value is not `null` before parsing it:

```
String parsedValue = DEFAULT_VALUE;
try {
  if (myValue != null) {
    parsedValue = parse(myValue);
  }
} catch (ParseException e) {
  log(e);
}
```

Regarding the code above, my question is, is it better to nest the `if` loop into the `try/catch` block or vice-versa?

In other words, is the previous code better or the following:

```
String parsedValue = DEFAULT_VALUE;
if (myValue != null) {
  try {
    parsedValue = parse(myValue);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    log(e);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: As @Brythan raised the issue, for simplicity, let's assume here that `log` is a method in a random logging library, and has the 2 signatures `log(Exception)` and `log(String)`. Like that we avoid creating an Exception to log a message, it makes the code clearer.

As @h.j.k raised another issue, here `myValue` could be `null`, this is no exceptional case, but if `myValue` has been assigned a value (not `null`), it should be parseable, and only in that case I expect an Exception to be thrown by `parse(String)`.

Comment: why don't you move the check in parse ?

Comment: @Blackbelt why not, as long as at the end of the try block, if `myValue` is null, `parsedValue` will have the value `DEFAULT_VALUE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put the `try`/`catch` over as little code as possible.  This also makes it easier to add an `else` case to the `if` statement if necessary.  For example:

```
String parsedValue = DEFAULT_VALUE;
if (myValue != null) {
  try {
    parsedValue = parse(myValue);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    log(e);
  }
} else {
  log(new Exception("Empty myValue!"));
}
```

This allows for more flexibility than the other version.

As a general rule, it's best to put as little code inside a `try` block as possible.  Only things that can throw an exception that should be caught by the `catch` and connecting code.  One reason is that other code than you originally intended may throw the exception and the solution in the `catch` block may not apply to the new case.

Comment: Same comment as the other answer: throwing exceptions is costly, so throwing an exception if `myValue` is null is not very nice.

Comment: @Vince  But I didn't throw an exception if `myValue` is `null`.  I logged a message.  For whatever reason, you made `log` take an exception as an argument.  So I generated one without throwing.  And really, that's beside the point.  It doesn't matter what you put in the `else` block.  The point is that this way you can easily add `else` code outside the `try`.  With the other version, you have to rewrite the code in order to do that.

Comment: my bad, I didn't know that the costly part is the `throw`. Also the log method is for clarity purpose (everyone has its own favourite logging system). I'll update the question to make that clearer but `log(String)` would look clearer to me.

Answer (score 3):

Short (and hopefully sweet) advice:

Are you able to modify `parse()` to throw a [`ParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) (I assuming you're talking about the linked one) if its argument is `null`? Something like:

```
String parse(Object input) {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new ParseException("null argument", -1);
    }
    ...
}
```

It then becomes the duty of `parse()` to validate its argument, and you can also eliminate the `null` check on the caller's side in this context.

I propose tweaking it slightly further (if you have no wish or intention to accidentally reassign `parsedValue` later):

```
final String parsedValue;
try {
    parsedValue = parse(myValue);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    log(e);
    parsedValue = DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
```

**edit:**

If you think that artificially throwing a `ParseException` for a `null` argument is fishy *and* you happen to be on `>=` Java 7, I will suggest this:

```
String parse(Object input) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(input);
    ...
}
```

and then

```
final String parsedValue;
try {
    parsedValue = parse(myValue);
} catch (ParseException | NullPointerException e) {
    log(e);
    parsedValue = DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
```

**edit 2:**

I have a line above that reads:

> It then becomes the duty of `parse()` to validate its argument, and you can also eliminate the `null` check on the caller's side in this context.

The first part is well-understood I hope, the "*in this context*" in the second part refers to whether to call `parse()` depending if `myValue` is `null`. Should you have additional logic in the current code block that depends on that condition, then yeah I guess it is also ok to be doing the explicit `null` check before calling `parse()`. However, you may then want to consider how to better handle multiple `null` checks...

Comment: Yeah but I rank the fact that an Exception is costly higher than the look of a try block and an if loop.

Comment: @Vince two points: 1) How widely used is `parse()` then? If it is used widely, then having to do a `null` check before every call may start to develop into a form of code smell. In fact, the simplest solution I can think of compared to what I put in my edit section is to simply call a method on `input`, and let the JVM throw the `NPE` by default when it really is `null`. Just remember to catch it on the caller side. This then becomes a trade-off between an implicit understanding and the explicit check using `Objects.requireNonNull`.

Comment: @Vince 2) A `try-catch` block incurs no cost so long as it doesn't throw an `Exception`, e.g. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16451908/2754160) or [here (which happens to be closely related to your question)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17966443/2754160). My advice simply begins with moving your `if` check on the caller side into the *called* method, and as long as `myValue` is not `null`, I believe it will be no costlier than what you have proposed in your question.

Comment: I understand your point, but I am worried in the case `myValue` is null. I am processing a list of values I parse, so if they are all null I may lose a noticeable fraction of second, and this is enough not to choose to throw the Exception (even if it is null). The Exception, I learned, is for exceptional cases, when you have no idea why it would do that. While having a null value can be common - and typically when no value has been assigned. But in the case null is not expected at all, I agree that would be a good solution.